# AngularJs problems with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with ng-repeat when i search for a car its done but i delete the name i searched for the cars doesn't back to the view this is my html:

```
<ion-content lazy-scroll ng-class="{expanded:isExpanded}">
 <div class="item-input-inset bar-light">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
    </label>

</div class="content has-header">
    <div>

        <div class="list animate-fade-slide-in-right">
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" ng-repeat='item in voitures[0] | filter: query' ng-model="data" ng-click="getID(item)" ui-sref="app.detailsVoiture({Id: item.idVoiture})">
                <img image-lazy-src="img/{{item.photo}}.jpg" image-lazy-loader="android" image-lazy-distance-from-bottom-to-load="-200" image-lazy-distance-from-right-to-load="-200">
                <h2 class="border-top" style="color:blue;">{{item.Modele.marque}} {{item.Modele.nom}}</h2>
                <p >{{item.categorie}}</p>
                <i class="icon ion-pricetag energized-900">{{item.prixLocation}}</i>
            </a>

    </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: The Angular `ng-repeat` feature works on data from the server as the page is rendered.  If you want to alter the data when you delete the name you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: Thinks u can put me exemple, haw i can use ajax

Comment: @MortadhaFadhlaoui: where you getting this data?If you can give me a sample demo.I will do it for you

Comment: @Muhsin the animation is what caused the problem , thinks

Comment: Could you please give a demo (Plunker/Fiddle/Codepen)?